# How to order SQL output in non trivial order?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to order my SQL output into a specific order, but there are lots of options so I can't just type them out.

I have a table with a column (binlocation) that has a string with 3 or 4 characters (depending on the following). All strings have the following format "letter number letter" with the following ranges {A-G}{1-30}{A-I} so look like this: A1A, A2A, ..., G30I

I have a very particular way I'd like them to be ordered but there are 1890 options so I can't just ordered by an array or similar.

I would like it ordered by the first value, then for each of the first values, I want it ordered by the second but for each of the second, ordered by the third. For example:
A1A, A1B, A1C, ..., A2A, A2B, A2C, ..., B1A, B1B, B1C, ... etc

To add another level of complexity, I want everything ending in 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'D' to appear first. So for example:
A1A, A1B, A1C, A1D, A2A, A2B, A2C, A2D, ..., G1A, G1B, G1C, G1D, G2A, G2B, G2C, G2D, ... A1E, A1F, A1G, A1H, A1I, A2E,A2F, ... etc.

What I have done so far is to split the string into 3 columns and then order the 3 columns accordingly:

```
select binlocation as "Bin", left(binlocation,1) as isle, cast(left(right(binlocation,length(binlocation)-1), length(binlocation)-2) as int) as row, right(binlocation,1) as height
from icprod
where discontinued = true
and quantityavailable >= 1
order by isle, row, height
```

This gets me the binlocation in the first order. However, I can't figure out how to only let it order height by A, B, C, D first. I was hoping it was as simple as doing a union of the 2 outputs:

```
select binlocation as "Bin", left(binlocation,1) as isle, cast(left(right(binlocation,length(binlocation)-1), length(binlocation)-2) as int) as row, right(binlocation,1) as height
from icprod
where discontinued = true
and quantityavailable >= 1
and right(binlocation,1) in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
order by isle, row, height

UNION

select binlocation as "Bin", left(binlocation,1) as isle, cast(left(right(binlocation,length(binlocation)-1), length(binlocation)-2) as int) as row, right(binlocation,1) as height
from icprod
where discontinued = true
and quantityavailable >= 1
and right(binlocation,1) in ('E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I')
order by isle, row, height
```

Threw a bunch of errors saying my columns are unexpected tokens.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Complex ordering is an application-level concern, imo. Is there a reason you absolutely have to do it in SQL?

Comment: I'm using an internal internal software called Accredo and SQL is the only language I know for pulling the data from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
order by (case when right(binlocation) in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') then 1 else 2 end),
         left(binlocation, 1),
         len(binlocation),
         binlocation
```

The logic is:

- Put the A/B/C/D ones first
- Then order by the first letter
- Order by the 3-digit values before the 4-digit values
- Order by the entire value (i.e. by the number)

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond but this solution works, when I initially tried it, it didn't work but I realised its just because of there was a bracket missing. Thanks for you help :)